# Comparing netstat scan from previous scans

Tags: windows-7, comparison, netstat

Lets say you want to compare new netstat scans from old ones to see changes in network connections. Is there a method or tool in windows 7 where you can view these changes?

Answer (score 0):

[TcpView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx) (or its console version `Tcpvcon` that comes together) is able to highlight changes as well to save views in file